# Error while sending stream to TCP port:- net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE - google-chrome

Tags: gstreamer-1.0

Currently, I am sending a stream to TCP port using Gstreamer and getting it on one HTML page. Video is working fine but the problem is with the audio; while opening that HTML page in firefox it is working but if I am opening the same in Google Chrome, I am getting an error : Failed to load resource: net:: ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Below is the Gstreamer command which I am using to send a stream:

**gst-launch-1.0 -v rtmpsrc location=rtmp://stream_url ! decodebin ! queue ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! oggmux ! tcpserversink host=host_ip port=port_number**